# Why does (.*)* make two matches and select nothing in group $1?

Tags: java, .net, regex, perl, language-agnostic

This arose from a discussion on formalizing regular expressions syntax. I've seen this behavior with several regular expression parsers, hence I tagged it language-agnostic.

Take the following expression (adjust it for your favorite language):

```
replace("input", "(.*)*", "$1")
```

it will return an empty string. Why?

More curiously even, the expression `replace("input", "(.*)*", "A$1B")` will return the string `ABAB`. Why the double empty match?

**Disclaimer:** I know about backtracking and greedy matches, but the rules laid out by [Jeffrey Friedl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) seem to dictate that `.*` matches everything and that no further backtracking or matching is done. Then why is `$1` empty?

**Note:** compare with `(.+)*`, which returns the input string. However, http://regexhero.com shows that there are still two matches, which seems odd for the same reasons as above.

Comment: The answer to this is likely to depend on the regex implementation (eg. to the degree does it stop as soon as there is a valid match).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the .\* consume the entire string in this Perl regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323613/why-doesnt-the-consume-the-entire-string-in-this-perl-regex)

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: almost the same indeed, but not a duplicate. It is language specific, and the answer does not explain what is explained here. Finally, the answer seems to contain an incorrect claim (that `(.*)*` will put the whole match in `$1`, which is precisely what this question shows is not true).

Comment: @Abel: In that question, the regex is `((.*)*)`, so the whole match *will* be placed in `$1`. (Of course, the outer parentheses are completely superfluous, but the answer *is* correct.)

Comment: @Tim: you're right, I only focused on this sentence: _$1 will contain what is matched by `(.*)*` / `(.+)*`, i.e. the whole string_ and interpreted it incorrectly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let's see what happens:

1. `(.*)` matches `"input"`.
2. `"input"` is captured into group `1`.
3. The regex engine is now positioned at the end of the string. But since `(.*)` is repeated, another match attempt is made:
4. `(.*)` matches the empty string after `"input"`.
5. The empty string is captured into group `1`, overwriting `"input"`.
6. `$1` now contains the empty string.

A good question from the comments:

> Then why does `replace("input", "(input)*", "A$1B")` return `"AinputBAB"`?

1. `(input)*` matches `"input"`. It is replaced by `"AinputB"`.
2. `(input)*` matches the empty string. It is replaced by `"AB"` (`$1` is empty because it didn't participate in the match).
3. Result: `"AinputBAB"`

Comment: Actually, `.*` is matching empty string at the start and end of the string. I tried it with `Matcher.find()` and print `matcher.group(1)` and `matcher.start()`. Strange that it prints the location `0`, and `5`, with empty string matched.

Comment: So, the behaviour is really strange for me.

Comment: Why it behaves different with `.+`?

Comment: @samuil: `.+` doesn't match the empty string.

Comment: @RohitJain Hence my comment on the Q: that expression can match in many ways: subtle implementation issues are likely to impact how aggressive the two `*` operators are.

Comment: @TimPietzcker.. Even worst, it is printing `null` at the end, for `(.+)*`. :( :(

Comment: This logic kind of follows what I figured so far. But greedy matching typically dictates that as soon as there's a positive match, no further matching is attempted (i.e., consider `.*(\d+)` against `hello 2013`. It will grab only one digit in `$1`). In other words, everything after (3) above should not happen, I think.

Comment: @RohitJain: I don't use Java, so I can't reproduce this. This sounds very strange, though. I can't imagine how there could be an empty match at the start of the string. `.*` is greedy, and there is no reason for backtracking...

Comment: @Richard.. But, why it's skipping `input`, and printing just the empty strings at the start and the end?

Comment: @TimPietzcker.. If you want I will post the code here. With the 4 combination I tried.

Comment: @Abel: Why not? The position at the end of the string is a valid position to start a match attempt.

Comment: The point is not that it should start a match attempt, the point is, greedy matching stops once a valid match is found. Apparently, that's not entirely true, as you said: implementations may treat this situation differently. Which is precisely why we are trying to formalize (parts of) regex syntax handling :).

Comment: That said, you do explain clearly what it actually going on under the hood.

Comment: Well, it does stop if you don't force it to go on with the outer `*` quantifier.

Comment: Hmm, testing with just `(.*)` also shows that it matches twice and matches two groups, second one being empty, yet the replace-expression does replace correctly. This may be a quirk of .NET though.

Comment: @Abel: `(.*)` matches twice because `.replace()` is run repeatedly until no more matches can be found. You don't notice it, though, because the second run replaces the empty string with itself because it's a new match. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: hmm... Then why replace("input", "(input)*", "A$1B") returns "AinputBAB"?

Comment: @AndriyF. I think that the same is true for `replace("input", "(.*)", "A$1B")`, which returns `AinputBAB`. Likewise, `replace("input", "(.*)*", "A$1B")` returns `ABAB` for the reasons Tim explains. Note, he updated his answer to respond to your comment.