# Strange issue with `(.*)*`, `(.*)+`, `(.+)*` in Java regex

Tags: java, regex

In order to re-produce the problem as stated in a recent question - [Why does (.*)* make two matches and select nothing in group $1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500095/why-does-makes-two-matches-and-selects-nothing-in-group-1) I tried various combination of `*` and `+`, inside and outside the brackets, and the result I got was not expected.

I would have expected the output, same as one explained in the accepted answer in that question, and also in another duplicate question, tagged under `Perl` - [Why doesn't the .* consume the entire string in this Perl regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323613/why-doesnt-the-consume-the-entire-string-in-this-perl-regex) . But it's not behaving the same way.

To make it simple, here's the code I tried: -

```
String str = "input";
String[] patterns = { "(.*)*", "(.*)+", "(.+)*", "(.+)+" };

for (String pattern: patterns) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.print("'" + matcher.group(1) + "' : '" + matcher.start() + "'" + "\t");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

And this is the output I got for all the 4 combination: -

```
'' : '0'    '' : '5'            // For `(.*)*`
'' : '0'    '' : '5'            // For `(.*)+`  
'input' : '0'   'null' : '5'    // For `(.+)*`
'input' : '0'                   // For `(.+)+`
```

Now, What I can't understand, why in `1st` and `2nd` output, I am not getting the entire string as `first result` for `matcher.find()`. I mean, ideally, in 1st case, `.*` should first capture the entire string, and then also capture the `empty string` at the end. Now, although it is giving expected result for 2nd match, it's not behaving well for `1st match`.

And also, in 2nd case, I should not even get the 2nd match, because I'm having a `+` quantifier outside the bracket.

My expected output is: -

```
'input' : '0'   '' : '5'  // For 1st
'input' : '0'    // For 2nd
```

Also, in the `3rd` output, why I got `null` as 2nd match instead of `empty string`? Shouldn't the 2nd match for first 3 combination be same?

4th output is as per expectation. So, no doubt in that.

Comment: Just a side note: Is there a reason for why you don't use a for-loop to loop through the regexes? Your code is reminding me about code from http://www.codecrap.com

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg. As I said, I was just reproducing the problem of a previous question. This is not a code that I;ll use. So, I just coded it in hurry. I'll modify it to look pretty.

Comment: Hint: Try `matcher.group(0)` to see the entire match, not just the first capturing group.

Comment: @TimPietzcker.. Ah! Holy freak. Got it now. Don't know why I forgot that since `*` is outside the group, it will not give entire match for `group(1)`. Silly fellow I'm. Thanks :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker.. You can add that to your answer also, to make it complete.

Comment: @Rohit: Did I miss where you did initialize the input `str` variable?

Comment: @Bergi.. Ah! Overwritten it while pasting new code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're seeing the effect of the same phenomenon you see in the question you linked to:

For `(.*)*`:

- The first `matcher.start()` is `0` because that's where the match (`"input"`) starts.
- The first `matcher.group(1)`  is `""` because the repeated `(.*)` has overwritten the captured `"input"` with the empty string (but `matcher.group(0)` does contain `input"`).
- The second `matcher.start()` is `5` because that's where the regex engine is after the first successful match.
- The second `matcher.group(1)` (as well as `matcher.group(0)`) is `""` because that's all there was to match at the end of the string.

For `(.*)+` it's the same. After all, the empty string can be repeated as many times as you want and still be the empty string.

For `(.+)*` you get `null` because while the second match succeeds (zero repetitions of a string of length 1 matches the empty string), the capturing parentheses haven't been able to capture anything, so its contents are `null` (as in undefined, instead of the empty string).